# Overriding a variable when extending a class with a different type in Java

Tags: java, templates, inheritance, types, extend

I want to extend a class as shown in the below example. 
While extending, I just want to change the type of one variable; declaring the same variable name with a different type will do this?

```
class Graph {
    LinkedList<Node> vertices;
}


class EntityGraph extends Graph {
    LinkedList<Entity> vertices; 
}
```

Comment: You cannot override variables!

Comment: okay, do you have any suggestion? :(

Comment: Try do it through java generics.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would want the same name for a different type?

Comment: because I want to reuse all the methods I wrote for Graph. All it needs to change is that the members of vertices is now "Entity", which is also a subclass of Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, making you variable acces type "protected" rather then default would be better in this scenario (i.e, make it protected in Graph class, and protected or less restrictive in EntityGraphClass).

Then you can type your Graph class such as :

```
class Graph<T> {

protected LinkedList<T> vertices;

}
```

then do a

```
class EntityGraph extends Graph<Entity> {
     //no longer needed
    //LinkedList<Entity> vertices; 
}
```

and you'll get an implementation of the Graph class (in the EntityGraph class) that has a List of Entity types;

If Entity extends Node, and you want the elements in the list to be of at least Node type, you can do:

```
class Graph<T extends Node> {

    protected LinkedList<T> vertices;

}
```

Comment: Just for the reference, **T** in `<T>` refers to a **Type**.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of overriding is only for non static member functions. Since different variablt type is required for `Entity Graph`, either you can declare member variable for `Entity Graph` or you can use getters and setters.

Setter in Entity Graph that will set the variable in super class by changing type.

Getter in Entity class that will get variable value from super class, type cast it and will return the value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override fields in Java. When you do what you have just shown us (which compiles fine), you'll only create a different version of the field `vertices` in the subclass.

So, if you do `Graph graph = new EntityGraph();`, `graph.vertices` will hold the value of the one in `EntityGraph`.

Answer (score 0):

you can not [override](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#Java) variables in Java.You can have variable with different name.